# Send chat request to all Gmail users

Tags: gmail, chat

I started my personal domain and configured Gmail to use as mail server. I imported all contacts from my old Gmail account to the new one. Now, how I can send chat request to all contacts from my new personal account? I know how to do it for a single contact, but repeating the same for thousands of contacts is tiresome. Is there any way to send the request to all Gmail contacts?

Comment: just send email to "*.*@gmail.com" ... wait

Comment: http://marketingconversation.com/2011/04/15/how-to-invite-multiple-contacts-to-your-google-chat/

Answer (score 2):

I have invited contacts to Google chat in 10 min with this.
Here is the procedure to do it in smart way,

1. Go to gmail web interface.
2. Click on **contacts**.
3. Search for 'gmail.com'.
4. Now you will get list of all contact who have `gmail.com` in it - **Click on 'select all'**
5. **Create group** - name it 'allgmail' (You can name anything you want).
6. **Compose a new email**
7. Type `allgmail` and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.
   You will fine that all the contact who has gmail.com is listed in TO:
   field.
8. Now copy all these contact.
9. If you are using Linux/Unix: If you have installed [Gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) Open Gedit, paste it in gedit and save file as **a.txt**. Apply this command in Gedit:

   `cat a.txt |  sed -e 's/,/,\n/g' | sed -e 's/".*"//g' | grep  -i @gmail.com > b.txt`

   If you are using Windows Then you will have to download [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/) Install it and place the a.txt in the root folder of CYGWIN(where the installation folder is) .Run the exact same command in Cygwin Terminal.

   This fill filter out unwanted character from a.txt and save into b.txt.
10. Now open b.txt. You will find all contacts who have @gmail.com in it.
11. Send them invitations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well. Everything went well. I used Regular Expression in Visual Studio IDE to remove special characters. Now it contains abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com,mno@gmail.com...

Now you said "Send them invitations". And I ask HOW ?
I did pasted every contacts to chat text box and selected "Invite to Chat". It ended with error :(

Comment: Try with inviting 100 contacts at a time.

Comment: I tried with just two contacts, it arised "Invalid address" message. I think, it does not support multiple addresses.

Comment: the format of the mail ids should be like <abc@gmail.com>,<xyz@gmail.com>,<mno@gmail.com>....it worked for me.

Comment: From the [link](http://marketingconversation.com/2011/04/15/how-to-invite-multiple-contacts-to-your-google-chat/)  @Rauf provided. if you click on the dropdown in the chat box and click `add contact' you will get a invitations page where you can paste your list of emails (formatted as comma separated). See this article for screen shots.

Answer (score -1):

Gmail has a feature that allows you to send bulk emails to a group of people versus individuals should send email. This feature can save hours of having to type an email address in at a time. Many Gmail users may be unaware of this feature or how to use them properly.

To send a mass email or you have a lot of follow STEPS below:

1. Login into your Gmail account using your email address and password.
2. Click on "Contacts" from the menu on the left corner of your site.
3. Click on the plus sign next to the two graphics. It is in the upper left corner. There are signs coupled with the first one, then the plus sign to the two people. This button allows you to create a new group.
4. Name your group and send it. Common name is "Family Member," "Friends," "Co-worker" or "Contact Business." After you click "Submit," the group's name will appear in the list.
5. Select "All Contacts" from your list. This is where all the contacts you have to go if you do not separate them into groups. A list of all your contacts will appear.
6. Check of the individual you want to put in a particular group by clicking your mouse on the blank box beside each person's name. When you are finished, click on "Groups" on the right list. A drop-down menu will appear that will say "Add to ...," then click the name of the folder that you added, and which will include contacts in the folder, which now can be emailed all together.
7. Click on the group you want to send bulk email to. It will show with all the email addresses, and you can click on an individual or a "select all." To the right of this list is the word "email." Click it, then display the new mail will appear to everyone in the group email address in the "To ".
8. Type in the subject. Then type your message and click "send."

Comment: @acoh Facha Did you read my question carefully. I am talking about sending chat request, NOT sending mails. Please revise your answer, otherwise you may get vote down from users.